# Delete cookie selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I understand that if I want to delete a cookie through Selenium I should do the next:

```
this.getDriverProvider().get().manage().deleteCookieNamed("cookie");
```

But, when I created this cookie I set:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name=cookie", "max_age=1200");
```

I found that if I want to delete this cookie, I have to pass `name=cookie` and not `cookie` alone. So, I don't understand how these pairs values are used then.

Please, can somebody help me?

Thanks,

Sarang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a cookie, you're passing `name=cookie` as its name. Constructor parameters are ordered and are mapped to its corresponding attribute so you don't have to specify that the first parameter will be the cookie's name.

If you were to add a value AFTER the creation, you invoke a method that will set the value you use as the value of the key associated to the method. For example:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("name", "value");
c.setVersion("cookieVersion"); //Here, the version key will have the "cookieVersion" value
c.setMaxAge(1200);
```

And then, when you invoke the getName() method you'll get the value associated to the key name, passed on the corresponding constructor. In your case is "name=cookie" and in my case is just "name".

If you feel like, you can check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html).

Comment: Hi. I was wrong using the constructor of the Cookie Class. Instead of use a String Options, I used a constructor with all parameter that I need to set my Cookie.                                            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry);